# Ubuntu, Seiko SLP 240, Commandline Printing

Tags: ubuntu, cups, lpr

I have bought an older label printer. The model is »Seiko SLP 240«. I have downloaded, build and installed the driver from the company's website. The printer is working, but it refuses to print the last ~3mm of the image. The command I am using is:

```
lpr -PSLP240 -o media=Custom.400x48mm -o landscape -o fitplot some.png
```

whereby »some.png« is 48mm x 400mm and rotated by 90° for printing.

If anybody has ever tried such a printer before, please let me know if there is a fix or workaround…

Thanks in Ahead!

Comment: Can you adjust the custom spec to make it 3mm longer?  If so, what happens?  Do you know what commandline options the SLP240 recognizes?

Comment: I did a quick check of the CUPS commandline options.  I didn't see fitplot, but fit-to-page is listed.

Comment: No matter how big the area is set to, it always prints only visible pixels of the image, so transparency does not work too.